# Title field returning &#039; where apostrophe should be?

Tags: 7, views, services

I have a series of fields on a View. For some reason, any node title field with an apostrophe in it is being returned to my endpoint as `Jen&#039;s Cupcake Store` instead of `Jenn's Cupcake Store`.

Any idea how I can fix this? Been at it for a few days now and I can't seem to find a single solid solution. Help is appreciated!

Comment: The string has been passed through htmlspecialchars, which is what Twig does to escape HTML:

```
php > echo htmlspecialchars("Jenn's Cupcake Store");
Jenn&#039;s Cupcake Store
```

Comment: This is done on purpose, otherwise a value returned from an endpoint would have apostrophes, breaking the response. Each programming language should have a function for decoding HTML entities. Decode the value on the receiving end, as its properly encoded for transport.

Comment: Try with htmlspecialchars_decode() or html_entity_decode().